# Looping through checked check-boxes then displaying result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an exercise where the user has to check correct answers from a list then press submit to see how well he/she did. However, my submit button does not seem to be working. Nothing happens when it is clicked. Here is the script:

```
<script>
//Returns how many correct answers were checked
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    var arrayScore = [];        
    var tempScore = 0;
    $('.confirmContainer').remove();
    $('.toggleConfirmList:checked').each(function(){
        arrayScore.push($(this).val());
    });
    for(var i=0; i<arrayScore.length; i++)
    {
        tempScore = arrayScore[i] + tempScore;  

    }

    $('feedback').show();
    $("#scoreArea").val(tempScore);     

});
</script>
```

Basically I want to disable the input container and then display the feedback after calculating the users score.

Here is the HTML code that the script uses:

```
<ol class="toggleConfirmList" start="1">
                        <!-- Start of toggleConfirm question -->
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">
                            <p class="question">What is your citizenship?
                            </p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                            </div>
                        </li>  
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">What is the purpose of your trip</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">How long will you be staying in Canada?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Where will you be staying?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">What is your occupation?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Do you have any family in Canada?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">How will you support yourself in Canada?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Do you intend to work or study while you are in Canada?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Have you ever been convicted of a criminal offence?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Do you suffer from any medical conditions?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">Have you ever been refused a visa to Canada?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggleConfirm">  
                            <p class="question">In which country do you reside permanently?</p>
                            <div class="toggleInputContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1">
                            </div>
                        </li>                                          
                  </ol>

                      <div class="confirmContainer">
           <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
           </div>
                      <div class="feedback">
                                    <strong>Answer:</strong>In the exercise you checked <span id="scoreArea">0</span> correct questions

                      </div>
```

Comment: `$('feedback').show();` should be `$('.feedback').show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for setting value to a span element you should use `text()` method instead of `val()`:

```
//Returns how many correct answers were checked
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    var arrayScore = [];        
    var tempScore = 0;
    $('.confirmContainer').remove();
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){ // for selecting checkboxes you can use ":checkbox" selector
        arrayScore.push(parseInt($(this).val())); // parseInt() the values
    });
    for(var i=0; i<arrayScore.length; i++)
    {
        tempScore = arrayScore[i] + tempScore;  

    }

    $('.feedback').show(); // class selectors should have '.'
    $("#scoreArea").text(tempScore); // use text() instead of val()    

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EWgzq/2/

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. I know these mistakes look pretty pitiful, but its my first coop workterm and I never did web development in my life :(

Comment: @user1410668 you are welcome, no, these are common mistakes, good luck.

Comment: May I also suggest couple of tweaks. First try using the `.toggleConfirmList input:checked` selector as it's gonna be a bit faster and clearer, also you might not need to push the values into the array at all (depending on your overall needs though of course) - you can just sum them up right in the each function - http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/EWgzq/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. It may be that it is executing before the DOM is ready.

```
<script>
//Returns how many correct answers were checked
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitButton').click(function(){
        var arrayScore = [];        
        var tempScore = 0;
        $('.confirmContainer').remove();
        $('.toggleConfirmList:checked').each(function(){
            arrayScore.push($(this).val());
        });
        for(var i=0; i<arrayScore.length; i++){
            tempScore = arrayScore[i] + tempScore;  
        }
        $('feedback').show();
        $("#scoreArea").val(tempScore);     
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Knyri that did it! However for some reason the 'scoreArea' element is constantly showing the score as whatever value I originally initialize 'tempScore' as. I think that my array doesn't seem to be pushing any elements inside it. Would the line:

        $('.toggleConfirmList:checked').each(function(){
Find all the checked checkboxes within that list?

Comment: You can alert in for loop and check if it is entering loop or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//Returns how many correct answers were checked
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    var arrayScore = [];        
    var tempScore = 0;
    $('.confirmContainer').remove();
    $('.toggleInputContainer input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        arrayScore.push($(this).val()*1); // See the *1
    });
    for(var i=0; i<arrayScore.length; i++)
    {
        tempScore = arrayScore[i] + tempScore;  

    }

    $('div.feedback').show(); // added div. it was missing.
    $("#scoreArea").html(tempScore);    // it should be .html() or .text() not .val(). The .val() works only for form elements 

});
</script>
```